# Byte Array to IPictureDisp

Tags: image, vb6, menu, icons, arrays

I have an Image in a Resource Dictionary, and I want to put it as an icon for a menu with SetMenuBitMaps API, so I have the byte array of the image in the Resource Dictionary, How can I convert the bytes into an IPictureDisp? I Found this :

```
      Private Declare Function CreateStreamOnHGlobal Lib "ole32.dll" (ByRef hGlobal As Any, ByVal fDeleteOnResume As Long, ByRef ppstr As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function OleLoadPicture Lib "olepro32.dll" (ByVal lpStream As IUnknown, ByVal lSize As Long, ByVal fRunMode As Long, ByRef riid As GUID, ByRef lplpObj As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function CLSIDFromString Lib "ole32.dll" (ByVal lpsz As Long, ByRef pclsid As GUID) As Long
Private Const SIPICTURE As String = "{7BF80980-BF32-101A-8BBB-00AA00300CAB}"
Public Function PictureFromArray(ByRef b() As Byte) As IPicture
      On Error GoTo errorhandler

      Dim istrm As IUnknown
      Dim tGuid As GUID

      If Not CreateStreamOnHGlobal(b(LBound(b)), False, istrm) Then
        CLSIDFromString StrPtr(SIPICTURE), tGuid
        OleLoadPicture istrm, UBound(b) - LBound(b) + 1, False, tGuid, PictureFromArray
      End If

      Set istrm = Nothing
      Exit Function
    errorhandler:
      Debug.Print "Could not convert to IPicture!"
    End Function
```

But it is not working for me, it always returns "Nothing".

Comment: What do you mean by "Resource Dictionary?" This is one of the things that the ImageList control is good for. You can select one of the images it holds by index or key using the ListImages property, then use the ExtractIcon method on that and take the Handle property of the Icon object to use in setting your menu item bitmap.

Comment: Yeah I know, but I need to put the Image inside of a dll. I'm creating dll's for each language my app will support, and I want to put an image corresponding the language. Resource Dictionary, well I meant Resource File, you know those with the RES extension in wich we can store any kind of resource.

Comment: Then why can't you use the LoadResPicture() function and use the handle of the resulting StdPicture/IPictureDisp object?